# How to give request to the admin by user created by admin

Tags: django, django-models

I have created an admin site and along with two users. Now user needs to request the admin to create, update and delete the topics. In the meantime, every user has to give access to delete their own created topic.
How to process this using Django?

**admin:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Question, Sub_Topic, SID,  Main_Topic, Subjects
admin.site.register(Question)
admin.site.register(SID)
admin.site.register(Subjects)
admin.site.register(Main_Topic)
admin.site.register(Sub_Topic)
```

**models:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from django.urls import reverse
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SID(models.Model):
    static_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.static_id

class Subjects(models.Model):
    subjects = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.subjects

class Question(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = ( 
    ('draft', 'Draft'), 
    ('published', 'Published'), 
)
    IMPORTANCE_SCORE = (
('LOW','Low'),
('NORMAL', 'Normal'),
('HIGH','High'),
)
    parentid = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    staticid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    qid = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    question = models.TextField()
    a= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    b= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    c= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    d= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    importance = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices= IMPORTANCE_SCORE, 
      default='LOW')
    complexity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    marks = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    foundation = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    core = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    exam = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    fscore = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    sscore = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    cscore = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    escore = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.qid, self.question)

class Main_Topic(models.Model):
    IMPORTANCE_SCORE = (
('LOW','Low'),
('NORMAL', 'Normal'),
('HIGH','High'),
)
    Main_Topic_Id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Main_Topic = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Num_Of_Sub_Topics =  models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    Num_Of_Questions = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    importance_score = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices= IMPORTANCE_SCORE, default='LOW')
    complexity_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    prerequisite = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Main_Topic

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('topic_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Sub_Topic(models.Model):
    IMPORTANCE_SCORE = (
('LOW','Low'),
('NORMAL', 'Normal'),
('HIGH','High'),
)
    staticid = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    sub_topic = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Num_Of_Sub_subTopics =  models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    Num_Of_Questions = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    importance = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices= IMPORTANCE_SCORE, 
    default='LOW')
    complexity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    prerequisite = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sub_topic
```

This is the model file I am using, I hope to need to modify the login in the admin panel. While first creating the admin using create superuser in the admin panel, admin can create the users and give permission.
If so user1 has some crud operations and user2 has some crud operations. But we need to keep those operations individual to them.

Comment: This is far too broad. Where exactly are you having trouble? Show some code.

Comment: I am getting trouble when user1 tries to delete a question created by user2. It's deleting, but I want user1 capable of deleting his own questions? How can I proceed with this? could you please do some support on this?

Comment: Not without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to rewrite admin site if you want to do that. But it will be too many to talk about it here. You may need to find a tutorial and to learn how to customize admin site.

I will recommend that instead of allowing user login to admin site, you can create your user admin site. On this page, user only can watch, update or delete their topic.

To do it, you need to have a line under the model class which you allow user to modify it.

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey('User', unique=True)
```

And when you try to update or delete, you can check if created_by = request.user (which is the user who currently login).